# syncing sound with CCAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCSpeed that contains a CCAnimation that dynamically changes it's speed based on stuff that's going on in the game. Is there any way i can get the animation to call a selector each time the animation "ticks" (switches frame), in this specific case, in order to play a sound?

Edit: Other solutions to sync the animation ticks with sound are welcome as well

Comment: I found out how to do it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19216789/129202

Comment: @Jonny I think I ended up using KVO on the displayFrame property of the sprite

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if QuartzCore/CADisplayLink might be what you're looking for.

You can create one with `-[UIScreen - displayLinkWithTarget:selector: ]`

You can get a callback for every screen refresh (VBL) cycle.

Comment: (Although I realize that's not specifically tied to your animation frames)