# Syncing sounds with frames inside CCAnimation for cocos2d 2.x*

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, synchronization, audio

How would I sync sound effects with an animation (CCAnimation)

```
        NSMutableArray* animationframes = [NSMutableArray array];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime01.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime02.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime03.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime04.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime05.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        [animationframes addObject:[[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[TitleLayer spriteframeForFile:@"title_startanime06.png"] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease]];
        CCAnimation* animation = [CCAnimation animationWithAnimationFrames:animationframes delayPerUnit:0.09 loops:1];
```

Can I add a callblock somehow to the animationframes array?

Or it could work if a CCAnimationFrame had a optional callback/delegate for when it's activated.

Comment: For now I found this: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forums/topic/usage-of-ccanimationframedisplayednotification/#post-409613 Will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok all we have to do is:

1. Observe the notification CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification.
   It's called on the sprite that is animated.
2. In order for the
   notification to be broadcast, a dictionary will need to be added
   to the CCSpriteFrame that you want to hook into. I added a NSDictionary
   containing the spriteframename of each sprite for all spriteframes
   since I need to hook all of them, but I guess the dictionary could
   be empty as well, just not `nil`.

   ```
       animationframe = [[[CCAnimationFrame alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:str] delayUnits:1 userInfo:nil] autorelease];
       animationframe.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:str, @"spriteframename", nil];
       [animationframes addObject:animationframe];

       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(frameupdatedinbootanimation:) name:CCAnimationFrameDisplayedNotification object:NULL];
   ```

Then catch it

```
-(void)frameupdatedinbootanimation:(id)hmm {
    NSLog(@"frameupdatedinbootanimation: %@", hmm);
    Do something here
```

Comment: as per the documentation. ymmv : i tried that for a critical aspect of game play (syncing an fx on attacker animation frame 9 for example). Especially in simulator, the FPS is a random number and often the notification was not being posted. I inferred this is because the frames are actually skipped ... so i ended up walking away from it.

Comment: There is a documentation (apart from source comments)? Anyways I also used this method to adjust sprite position as well, as my designer sent me different origins for each frame. Duh. So I ended up making a small API there (pos key in dic would mean origin change), because you can only have one handler per notification. Makes me wish someone would bake this into the CCAction flow too some day.

Comment: lol, that was just a 'snarky' about documentation. Notin, nada, null, rien !  Anyways, if all you are doing is adjusting something per frame (position, transparency, etc ...) and the nature of what needs to be done is in the dictionary (ergo api), it will work for you. If you need to do something critical to game play (as i did), avoid this.